# Start an Android application via a shell script?

Tags: shell, terminal, command-line, scripts

Is it possible to start an actual Android application from the command line in Android? For example, say I'd simply like to start/bring to the front my calendar. Is there a way that I can do this like:

```
startapp com.google.calendar
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using adb, I believe it is possible:

```
am [start|instrument]
am start [-a <action>] [-d <data_uri>] [-t <mime_type>]
[-c <category> [-c <category>] ...]
[-e <extra_key> <extra_value> [-e <extra_key> <extra_value> ...]
[-n <component>] [-D] [<uri>]
am instrument [-e <arg_name> <arg_value>] [-p <prof_file>]
[-w] <component>
```

for example we have android program with Manifest as under:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.app1.android.xtract">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon">
   <activity class=".Contact" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:value="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:value="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
  </activity>
 </application>
.
.
</manifest>
```

To run the code issue command like this (in one line):

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.app1.android.xtract/com.app1.android.xtract.Contact
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work over SSH for me, but it does when running `adb` so I'll give you that :)

Answer (score 0):

All apps have different activities. There is an app that will help called [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut&hl=en) that will assist you if you don't want to start decompiling apps to see their manifest files. Think you need to be root though to open apps via terminal.

```
# Examples

# From terminal emulator or adb as root open settings
am start com.android.settings/.Settings

# From ssh as root open settings
adb shell am start com.android.settings/.Settings

#Function to download a given url with chrome or stock browser
downloadurl(){ if [ $(pm list packages | grep -e 'com.android.chrome') ]; then am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main -d $1; sleep 10; input keyevent 4; return; fi; if [ $(pm list packages | grep -e 'com.android.browser') ]; then am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -n com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity -d $1 && sleep 5; input keyevent 4; return; fi; am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d $1 && sleep 10; input keyevent 4; }
downloadurl "http://your.site.file.example.zip"
```